# What's the best way to create a static page in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've created some resources in my Ruby on Rails application:

```
localhost/admin/books
localhost/admin/users
localhost/admin/...
```

Now I want to create a static page which just contains links to these resources and is accessible from `localhost/admin`

I've tried to create the page in `/public/admin/index.html` and it works, but unfortunately I have to duplicate the layout of my resource controllers in that file.

Is there any other way to create a static page?

**EDIT:** With "static page" I don't mean a static page in that sense that the *source* of that page is static. I mean that the *content* is static, i.e. is not generated by a model and/or from database.

Comment: I'm confused .. you're saying that you want to have a static page, but you don't want to duplicate the layout of your resource controllers? A static page is precisely what you did with putting the page in public/admin/index.html.

Comment: Yes, I did :) And I'm also saying that I'm not happy with that and hence asking for a different approach.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just create a view with the contents you'd have for the page, call it `index.html.erb`, and leave the action method in the controller as a no-op.

Use [page caching](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#page-caching) for bonus points.

Answer (score 2):

[Ryan Bates](http://railscasts.com) has a [screencast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/117-semi-static-pages) on this topic.

Answer (score 0):

For now it's better to use `high_voltage` gem: https://github.com/thoughtbot/high_voltage

Just create `pages` directory in `views`, add pages there, and use links like `link_to 'About', page_path('about')`